# How to convert List to ListBuffer?

Tags: list, scala, listbuffer

Is there any way to efficiently do this, perhaps through toBuffer or to methods? My real problem is I'm building a List off a parser, as follows:

```
lazy val nodes: Parser[List[Node]] = phrase(( nodeA | nodeB | nodeC).*)
```

But after building it, I want it to be a buffer instead - I'm just not sure how to build a buffer straight from the parser.

Comment: Is your concern that `toBuffer` is not sufficiently performant?

Comment: If I understand correctly, He wants a `ListBuffer`, not just any `Buffer` as returned by `toBuffer`

Comment: Yeah, I need a ListBuffer. Performance is simply a concern because I'd like to know what's the cost of the conversion (I assume linear), but since this is just part of an initialization step, that might be acceptable.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`to` indeed does the trick, and it is pretty trivial to use:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scala> l.to[ListBuffer]
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

Works in scala 2.10.x

For scala 2.9.x, you can do:

```
scala> ListBuffer.empty ++= l
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Nice; +1!  Just when I was thinking the collections API couldn't be any more magical (from the perspective of 2.8) ...

Comment: `++=` will reuse the same `ListBuffer` instead of creating an empty one and then throwing it away again.  (Not that creating an empty `ListBuffer` is particularly expensive.)

Comment: With `Scala 2.13`: `List(1,2,3).to(collection.mutable.ListBuffer)` (requires simple parentheses).

Comment: @XavierGuihot Thanks . it worked in 2.13. But any idea why in 2.13 it only needs simple paranthesis?